# G1 GC -- extremely long termination time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

A seemingly straightforward question: why does G1 GC spend so much time in the 'termination' phase? A non-full GC takes ~2 seconds, and from that, 1.5 sec is the termination (work stealing) phase.

Context:
- our app has apprx. 10MB/sec allocation rate
- most of those are short-lived objects
- termination time is increasing linearly with app uptime 
- we have a large heap (24G)
- full GC never occurs, if I force it manually then GC times are back to normal
- the app itself does a lot of classloading (JSP)
- we're using G1 GC with the following parameters:

```
-XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:CICompilerCount=4 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8388608 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=35 -XX:InitialHeapSize=17179869184 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MarkStackSize=4194304 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 -XX:MaxHeapSize=23622320128 -XX:MaxNewSize=14168358912 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=8388608 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintStringDeduplicationStatistics -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication

122618.508: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 645922816 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:   11770408 bytes,   11770408 total
- age   2:    4473200 bytes,   16243608 total
- age   3:    7342504 bytes,   23586112 total
- age   4:    2872344 bytes,   26458456 total
- age   5:    3291816 bytes,   29750272 total
- age   6:    3174480 bytes,   32924752 total
- age   7:    3538032 bytes,   36462784 total
- age   8:    3236984 bytes,   39699768 total
- age   9:    3369896 bytes,   43069664 total
- age  10:    4028056 bytes,   47097720 total
- age  11:    3598376 bytes,   50696096 total
- age  12:    3829808 bytes,   54525904 total
- age  13:    3966344 bytes,   58492248 total
- age  14:    3347280 bytes,   61839528 total
- age  15:    3887528 bytes,   65727056 total
 122618.508: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 7510, predicted base time: 297.79 ms, remaining time: 1202.21 ms, target pause time: 1500.00 ms]
 122618.508: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 1208 regions, survivors: 20 regions, predicted young region time: 157.92 ms]
 122618.508: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 1208 regions, survivors: 20 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 455.71 ms, target pause time: 1500.00 ms]
, 2.1182594 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 2094.7 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 122618508.2, Avg: 122618508.3, Max: 122618508.4, Diff: 0.3]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 3.0, Avg: 283.6, Max: 2094.1, Diff: 2091.1, Sum: 2269.0]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 2.2, Max: 4.3, Diff: 4.3, Sum: 17.2]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 7.4, Max: 24, Diff: 24, Sum: 59]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.3, Max: 0.5, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 2.4]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 0.3]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 283.7, Max: 341.0, Diff: 340.9, Sum: 2269.5]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 1524.5, Max: 1754.8, Diff: 1754.8, Sum: 12196.2]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 10989.2, Max: 18096, Diff: 18095, Sum: 87914]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.6]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 2094.3, Avg: 2094.4, Max: 2094.6, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 16755.2]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 122620602.7, Avg: 122620602.7, Max: 122620602.8, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.2 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [String Dedup Fixup: 4.5 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [Queue Fixup (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Table Fixup (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 3.7, Max: 4.3, Diff: 4.3, Sum: 29.7]
   [Clear CT: 1.7 ms]
   [Other: 17.1 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 14.6 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.4 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 1.5 ms]
   [Eden: 9664.0M(9664.0M)->0.0B(9688.0M) Survivors: 160.0M->136.0M Heap: 10.5G(16.0G)->1101.1M(16.0G)]
 [Times: user=14.38 sys=0.07, real=2.12 secs] 
122620.627: [GC concurrent-string-deduplication, 142.3K->26.4K(115.9K), avg 60.3%, 0.0010556 secs]
   [Last Exec: 0.0010556 secs, Idle: 450.5150579 secs, Blocked: 0/0.0000000 secs]
      [Inspected:            2027]
         [Skipped:              0(  0.0%)]
         [Hashed:            1304( 64.3%)]
         [Known:              602( 29.7%)]
         [New:               1425( 70.3%)    142.3K]
      [Deduplicated:         1240( 87.0%)    115.9K( 81.4%)]
         [Young:             1240(100.0%)    115.9K(100.0%)]
         [Old:                  0(  0.0%)      0.0B(  0.0%)]
   [Total Exec: 277/0.4346528 secs, Idle: 277/122619.8157354 secs, Blocked: 62/0.0449930 secs]
      [Inspected:          801984]
         [Skipped:              0(  0.0%)]
         [Hashed:          411526( 51.3%)]
         [Known:           245334( 30.6%)]
         [New:             556650( 69.4%)     53.2M]
      [Deduplicated:       403870( 72.6%)     32.1M( 60.3%)]
         [Young:           392678( 97.2%)     31.1M( 96.8%)]
         [Old:              11192(  2.8%)   1066.4K(  3.2%)]
   [Table]
      [Memory Usage: 8812.9K]
      [Size: 262144, Min: 1024, Max: 16777216]
      [Entries: 288637, Load: 110.1%, Cached: 0, Added: 358165, Removed: 69528]
      [Resize Count: 8, Shrink Threshold: 174762(66.7%), Grow Threshold: 524288(200.0%)]
      [Rehash Count: 0, Rehash Threshold: 120, Hash Seed: 0x0]
      [Age Threshold: 3]
   [Queue]
      [Dropped: 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the logs again, the problem is not the termination time -- it's the `Ext Root Scanning` -- the termination time is long because those threads are waiting for the other workers to finish RS. This is because use the code cache is getting progressively larger.