# Why are G1 garbage collector Unloading times increasing over time?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, solaris, g1gc

I'm experiencing a strange behavior when using the G1 garbage collector when running Glassfish under Solaris (SPARC) with the JDK 8u172, the `Unloading` time of the `Remark` phase is very long and increasing over time.

Here is an extract of the logs just after the start-up of the application server :

> 2018-10-18T10:08:28.362+0200: 9528.430: [GC remark 2018-10-18T10:08:28.362+0200: 9528.430: [Finalize Marking, 0.0012164 secs] 2018-10-18T10:08:28.363+0200: 9528.431: [GC ref-proc, 0.1783250 secs] 2018-10-18T10:08:28.541+0200: 9528.609: [Unloading, **1.4087725 secs**], 1.5954223 secs]
>    [Times: user=10.79 sys=0.04, real=1.60 secs]

And after some days :

> 2018-10-22T20:24:52.070+0200: 392111.556: [GC remark 2018-10-22T20:24:52.070+0200: 392111.556: [Finalize Marking, 0.0010811 secs] 2018-10-22T20:24:52.072+0200: 392111.557: [GC ref-proc, 0.1432306 secs] 2018-10-22T20:24:52.215+0200: 392111.701: [Unloading, **5.4160564 secs**], 5.5672543 secs]
>    [Times: user=41.16 sys=0.06, real=5.57 secs]

As you can see, the `Unloading` time grew from 1.6s to 5.6s.

Here is a graph of the `Unloading` times over time :

[image: increasing unloading times over time]

As you can see, it's increasing more or less linearly over time.

Here are the relevant command line flags :

> -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:GCLogFileSize=10485760 -XX:InitialHeapSize=8589934592 -XX:MaxHeapSize=8589934592 -XX:MetaspaceSize=536870912 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+UseLargePagesInMetaspace

The flag `-XX:+UseLargePagesInMetaspace` was added after reading [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/long-class-unloading-pauses-with-jdk8), but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. I also had a look at [this other blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/troubleshooting-long-gc-pauses) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507929/latencies-issues-which-g1gc), but unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions seems to apply in this case.

I can't reproduce this bug when the Glassfish server is running under other Operating Systems/architectures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the JDK : [JDK-8199406 : Performance drop with Java JDK 1.8.0_162-b32](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8199406).

From the bug description, and [this discussion thread](https://markmail.org/message/oygxxbaeuraiocy4?q=net%2Ejava%2Eopenjdk&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20MarkmailNetjavaopenjdk%20%28Follow%20OpenJDK%20development%20e-mail%20traffic%29), this bug :

- is a regression introduced in JDK 8u161 affecting Garbage Collecting
- is specific to Solaris : "*there are reports of performance drops on Solaris SPARC 64*" ; "*On x86 it is really fast.*"
- increases class-unloading time : "*This is a regression that got introduced in 8u161 that increased the class-unloading times from an average of 0.65 secs to 10s of seconds for the customer.*"
- is fixed in JDK 8u181/8u182.

The migration to JDK 8u192 fixed the bug, the `Unloading` times are now much smaller and constants :

> 2018-10-24T11:57:48.479+0200: 96295.786: [GC remark 2018-10-24T11:57:48.480+0200: 96295.786: [Finalize Marking, 0.0012370 secs] 2018-10-24T11:57:48.481+0200: 96295.787: [GC ref-proc, 0.0960026 secs] 2018-10-24T11:57:48.577+0200: 96295.883: [Unloading, **0.2760147 secs**], 0.3796341 secs]
>    [Times: user=1.51 sys=0.02, real=0.38 secs]